# Get all product images from Amazon Advertising Product API

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

The documented Images request in the docs will return me only the first image (the one Amazon uses in their product listings): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingImages.html

How can I retrieve all the images on a product?

Here is my code, which will always result in just one product image instead of all:

```
resp = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(asin, { response_group: 'Offers,Images', country: 'de' })
item = resp.get_element('Item')
images = []
images.push(item.get_hash('LargeImage'))
```

Comment: whats your code look like so far??

Comment: I don't think the code is relevant, as the API response from Amazon is already missing these images. Everything further is just transforming the response to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All images are in `<ImageSets>` section of the response.
I think that you can do it using `get_array` method:

```
resp = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(asin, { response_group: 'Offers,Images', country: 'de' })
item = resp.get_element('Item')
images = item.get_array('ImageSets/ImageSet/LargeImage'‌​)
```